# How to prevent MongoDB nodeJS driver to crash my entire app/process in case of failure?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, exception, database-connection

I'm currently stress-testing a nodeJS API which is integrating a MongoDB connection.

It works fine when not too many concurrent connections are being handled (1 per second, and every connection closed after transaction), but when the number of concurrent connections is growing significantly, the connection is crashing and so is my process and then I've got to restart manually the server.

```js
Error: Module did not self-register: '/Users/david/myproject/node_modules/fs-ext/build/Release/fs-ext.node'.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/david/myproject/node_modules/fs-ext/fs-ext.js:22:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
```

Is there any way to prevent the server to crash and to handle this exception rather than having to restart it every time it fails like that?

Here's my code:

```js
Promise.resolve(MongoClient.connect(`${url}`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            numberOfRetries: 3
        }))
            .then((db) =>  {
               // interact with the database
            })
```

MongoDB is dockerized, and I'm using `NodeJS v15.0.1`,
The driver is `"mongodb": "3.6.3"`

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution?